# How to get object from json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting following response from jquery ajax in json (in response array)

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data fetched successfully",
    "data": [{
        "id": "19",
        "employer_id": "5bea870168ebeb6db4d612c3",
        "employee_id": "5bea868b68ebeb6db4d612c1"
    }],
    "count": 1
}
```

How can i get "count" object in javascript/jquery from this json (not in php) ?

i tried with following code but not working for me

`alert(response.count)`;

Comment: `response.count` should have worked. Did you remember to do `dataType: 'json'` so that jQuery would parse the JSON for you?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should console.log(data) in success function, with your object response.count still worked.

If response is array you can use `console.log(response[0].count);`

```js
let response = {
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data fetched successfully",
    "data": [{
        "id": "19",
        "employer_id": "5bea870168ebeb6db4d612c3",
        "employee_id": "5bea868b68ebeb6db4d612c1"
    }],
    "count": 1
};
console.log(response.count);

response = [{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Data fetched successfully",
    "data": [{
        "id": "19",
        "employer_id": "5bea870168ebeb6db4d612c3",
        "employee_id": "5bea868b68ebeb6db4d612c1"
    }],
    "count": 1
}];

console.log(response[0].count);
```

Comment: The question says he tried this and it didn't work.